# BIND9: Host xxxxx not found: 2(SERVFAIL)

Tags: bind, ubuntu-22.04

I've installed and set up the bind9 DNS server on UbuntuServer 22.04.3.

Then I've checked my hosts. And I have got an error:

```bash
host host1
Host host1 not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

But the reverse operation works without any problem.

```bash
host 192.168.0.16
16.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer host1.
```

My forward zone is:

```bash
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.obfuscated.com. root.ns.obfuscated.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
@       IN      NS      ns.obfuscated.com.

; name servers - A records
ns  IN A       192.168.0.101

; 192.168.0.0/24 - A records
host3   IN A     192.168.0.201 ; 
host2   IN A     192.168.0.250 ; 
host1   IN A     192.168.0.16  ;
```

The zones file is:

```bash
zone "obfuscated.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/forward.bind";
        check-names ignore;
        };
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/reverse.bind";
        check-names ignore;
         };
```

The Netplan config:

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.101/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.1]
        search: [ obfuscated.com ]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
```

I'm positive in mistakes of the forward.bind file, but can't find them. The `named-checkzone` command has no errors.

Comment: Simplified: DNS only works for FQDN's and requires that a resolver appends a search domain to unqualified / short hostnames before using DNS to resolve them. What happens when you directly query  your name server with the FQDN?  `dig host1.obfuscated.com. @192.168.0.101`

Comment: HBruijn, I have that answer: ```;; QUESTION SECTION:
;host1.obfuscated.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
host1.obfuscated.com. 604800 IN A 192.168.0.16

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.101#53(192.168.0.101) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 21 14:06:46 MSK 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97
```

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with how bind is configured. I never use `host` but if that is a utility to query DNS it probably expects, like `dig`  a FQDN and doesn't append the search domain to short hostnames. If that is the case, then  there was no fault, except in how you went about testing. `getent hosts shortname`  is the tool to test how the system resolver library works (as that honors `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, /`etc/hosts`,  search domains and more)

Comment: @HBruijn no, `host` uses system resolver settings, e.g. `resolv.conf` or whatever. It respects the search suffixes specified there. Very useful tool to check the local resolver, and as we see here, it seems it isn't configured correctly. But `SERVFAIL` is strange. I'd run `host -v host1` to see more details about the query it sent; however, if the problem is resolver, I am not familiar with Netplan, I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @HBruijn, and what if I need to use only shortnames?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, there's a result: ```host -v host1
Trying "host1.obfuscated.com"
Trying "host1"
Host host1 not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
Received 29 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 0 ms
 ```